# In the ruby console how to add a new record to a related table thru the parent table in the console?

Tags: ruby, console, irb

```
parent table = cars
related table = parts

c = car.find_by_id(1)
c.part.new(:car_id => 1, :part_name =>  "gas pedal", :color => "black")
```

I can't get this to work.

How can I do this?  How do I find what methods I can use for this relationship?

Comment: What did you intend by the first line (and by extension, the second line)?  Did you intend `parent(table = cars)` or did you intend something like `parent_table = cars`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
c = Car.find_by_id(1)
c.parts.create(:part_name =>  "gas pedal", :color => "black")
```

i am assuming you have a car has_many parts relationship defined.